# how to integrate ffmpeg gl-transition project in my existing project

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-transitions

i want to add trasition effect between images of video so i used https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition for video trasition effect but Building command not work in my android studio.
1.git clone http://source.ffmpeg.org/git/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg.
2.cd ffmpeg.
first two command run successfully in android studio terminal.
when try to run "ln -s ~/ffmpeg-gl-transition/vf_gltransition.c libavfilter/" 
get error:

screen shot1
[image]

when run command "git apply ~/ffmpeg-gl-transition/ffmpeg.diff"
get error:

screen shot2
[image]
and run command "./configure --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-opengl \
            --enable-filter=gltransition --extra-libs='-lGLEW -lglfw'"
get error:

screen shot3
[image]
i use com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2 for create normal video.please tell me how to integrate library in my project or any anotherway to do this

Comment: I am facing the same issue. have you got the solution if yes please can you describe how can we achieve this?

Comment: @manishthanki No, unfortunately.

Comment: The instructions have changed "a bit" but basically you need to substitute, from the directions `~/ffmpeg-gl-transition` with wherever you actually checked that source out locally...

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS you need: `brew install glew glfw3`. try and resolve!